# Mnesia write fails

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I defined a record named `log`. I want to create an mnesia table with name `log_table`. When I try to write a record to table, I get `bad_type` error as follows:

```
(node1@kitt)4> mnesia:create_table(log_table, [{ram_copies, [node()]}, 
                                               {attributes, record_info(fields, log)}]).
{atomic,ok}

(node1@kitt)5> mnesia:dirty_write(log_table, #log{id="hebelek"}).
** exception exit: {aborted,{bad_type,#log{id = "hebelek"}}}
in function  mnesia:abort/1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the record name is assumed to be the same as the table name.

To fix this you should either name your table just `log` or append the option `{record_name, log}` in your table options (as you've done in your fix).

It is usually good practice to let your record and table be named the same thing, it makes the code easier to read and debug. You can also then use the `mnesia:write/1` function with just your record as only argument. Mnesia then figures out which table to put the record in by looking at the name.

Answer (score 2):

I've found it. When I changed `mnesia:create_table` call to this

```
mnesia:create_table(log_table, [{ram_copies, [node()]},
                                {record_name, log},
                                {attributes, record_info(fields, log)}]).
```

everything works OK.

Answer (score 0):

How does your definition of the log-records look? Do you get the same error if you create a new table from scratch (i.e. remove the Mnesia@ directory first).